# Symfony - Import JMSSerializer in a service

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, service, yaml

I am building a little service who take in ouput an xml url and who return an object (serialization).

I need to import JMSSerializer in my service but it does not wok with this conf :

```
services:
    blace.parsexml:
        class: BB\BlaceBundle\Services\BlaceParseXML
        arguments: ['@jms_serializer']
```

And how i can use jmsserializer in my service (because $this->get('...') does not work).

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the constructor of your service class? I bet, there is an error message thrown, too. The symfony debugger does never print out "It doesnt work" ;-)